# "Static" attributes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive which generates a large amount of html input[type="radio"] with ng-repeat. Each of them has a number of attributes assigned.

Basically:

```
<div ng-repeat"day in days">
  <label ng-repeat="slot in day.slots">
    <input type="radio" class="{{slot.class}}" value="{{slot.value}}" ng-disabled="{{slot.disabled}}">
  </label>
</div>
```

The problem is that angular adds a watcher for each attribute of each input element and it consumes a lot of resources. The attributes won't change if `days` doesn't change. Is there any way I can make the attributes static and still use ng-repeat? Or must i generate the template in some other way? In that case, how would I do it and still have it re-render when `days` change?

Update: Clarified that it wasn't just the class attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-class`.

```
<input type="radio" ng-class="slot.class" />
```

The watcher is still bound, but the class attribute is not set everytime a digest happens, only when the value of `slot.class` changes.

Edit: Updated to reflect what original poster wanted.

I'm not sure if this is even a good practise, but you could try to write a directive that will generate a 'dumb' template by deregistering all the watchers. That way, only if the result of a watch statement changes, will you be updating the template.

Something like this:

```
module.directive('shallowWatch', function($compile){
    return {
        compile : function(tElement, tAttrs){
            var templateFN = $compile(tElement.html());
            tElement.empty();
            return function(scope, element, attrs){
                var childScope;
                scope.watch(attrs.shallowWatch, function(){
                    element.empty();
                    if(childScope){
                        childScope.$destroy();
                    }
                    childScope = scope.$new();
                    element.append(templateFn(childScope));
                    traverseScope(childScope, function(scope){
                        scope.$$watchers = [];
                    });
                });
            };
        }
    };

    function traverseScope(target, fn){
        var current, next;
        current = target;
        do {
            fn.apply(current, [current]);

            //depth-first traversal pulled from angularjs core
            if (!(next = (current.$$childHead || (current !== target && current.$$nextSibling)))) {
                while(current !== target && !(next = current.$$nextSibling)) {
                    current = current.$parent;
                }
            }
        } while ((current = next));
    }
});
```

You'd use it like so:

```
<div shallow-watch="days">
    <div ng-repeat"day in days">
      <label ng-repeat="slot in day.slots">
        <input type="radio" class="{{slot.class}}" value="{{slot.value}}" ng-disabled="{{slot.disabled}}">
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. Was unclear with my whole problem which is that I have many attributes for each input element.